# start external cmd prompt and update it concurrently with java application

Tags: cmd, prompt, processbuilder

I want to be able to run an external cmd prompt concurrently with my Java code. While running java application need to start external cmd prompt ,and this command prompt need to updated from my java application as well as i need to get values from this command prompt into java application.Please provide suitable suggestion

Comment: WHY DO WANT TO DO THAT

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start command");
```

**UPDATION 2**

To execute commands try this

```
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start cmd.exe /k \"ping localhost\"");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. can i able to read or write some command on already running command prompt from java code

Comment: mark it as answer if you feel its the correct requirement for your question